# Android: Please suggest me the effective approach to how to keep data of media player buffer temporarily

Tags: android

I have a situation where i want to store the last buffered media  when streaming any video file from android media player so that when one try to replay it it does not ave to re buffer it all over again.

*How to get data stored in media player buffer and if i happen to store the data then also in case when i reach on last i would need to have buffer of start data if file is of larger size this will make it more sophisticated?*

Please suggest me the effective approach to how to keep data of media player buffer temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your goal is to start playing a media file at a relatively exact time, I did a hacky thing once.

Set your volume to zero.

Start playing.

Have a loop wake up and check to see position periodically.

If position is > 0, the file has buffered and started.

Pause.

Set position back to 0.

Reset volume.

In my tests, when you play again, the file will be buffered in memory.  You'll need to try this yourself.

As for keeping file data in memory yourself, now you're talking about lower level apis.  For audio, something like Opensl.  For video, the MediaCodec stuff (4.1+).  For both together, you've got a lot of reading ahead of you.  I've written a native audio/video encoder, but that was a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks a heap for your answer
i will try and then update whether this work for me or not...